# System theme broken with Firefox 115, any way to fix it?

Tags: firefox, color-theme

My Firefox was just updated to 115 and the system theme is (in my opinion) broken: the tab bar gets a "selected" color all the time while the windows is active, which is horrendous. It was fine before.

Just an example:
[image]

The yellow highlight in the (background) Deluge window is fine, but I don't need/want the permanent yellow highlight in the tab bar. The same happens with the menu bar if I show it. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is being tracked in their bug tracker as [#1838460 Using titlebar colour to render menu bar & tabs looks badly in some themes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1838460).  I only skimmed the comments, but didn't see a way to fix it short of building locally with the proposed fix.